# Search a list for current sheet then show specific cell in that sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've been using the below formula which is supposed to search a list of tab names in range AK17:AK32 and then if the user is on that current tab it will then show the corresponding result of the cell in range AV17:AV32.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""&AK17&"!AV17"), IFERROR(NOW()/0)*1&"")
```

Up until recently, it appeared to do what was needed however now it appears to only show the result of cell AV17 regardless of what tab the user is currently on.

The list of agents in column AK can change and is used to create the tab names each month hence why I was using the INDIRECT function. Is there an easier way I could implement this that would work better?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: To confirm, the formula sits in the range X6: X10. The link to the sheet is as follows, if you need any other info please don't hesitate to ask: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165mN4q6gQBmC99ytdW5X78SAtjSlWv7ley__kVGoZ-c/edit#gid=266599213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> search a list of tab names in range AK17:AK32 and then if the user is on that current tab

To find a value in the *current tab*, you do not need to use `indirect()`. Put the agent name in cell `I2` and use this formula instead:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    hlookup( 
      W6:W10, 
      AV16:AZ, 
      match(I2, AK17:AK32, 0) + 1, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This is an array formula that will automatically fill cells `Y6:Y10`. To fill another number of cells, modify the parameter `W6:W10` accordingly.

See cell `Matt!Y6` in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165mN4q6gQBmC99ytdW5X78SAtjSlWv7ley__kVGoZ-c/edit#gid=266599213).

Comment: Only issue with that is that I need the formula to be automatic if possible which is why  was using the INDIRECT. If there was a way cell Y6 could populate with the current sheet name that may work?

Comment: You are looking for values in the _current sheet_, so you do not need a sheet name but an agent name. There may be a sheet by the name of each agent, but you should still not confuse the two. You can automate the formula by populating cell `I2` (_not_ cell `Y6`) with the sheet name. One way to do that is to use the [SheetName()](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95595167?msgid=95630115) custom function.

Comment: Apologies, i thought as it didn't fully answer the question I needed to reclarify in the comments but on reflection, I will use this answer and use a drop-down in I2 pulling names from column AK for the user to manually choose the name to populate.